# keycloak Error! Logged in user does not have an e-mail

Tags: spring, keycloak, jhipster

when setup my email configration inside keyclock realm
and after click to test conection i have this error `Error! Logged in user does not have an e-mail.`

and this is image to explain my problem

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Error is exactly what it is said. You have to add email address for the user by which you logged in to Keycloak Admin Console.

Go to `Manage Account(http://<host>/auth/admin/master/console/) -> Personal Info -> Update firstName/lastName/emailAddress -> Save` and try to add smtp configuration again.[image]

Comment: okay but after updated it  the error is changed. the error says ```Error! Failed to send email```

Comment: May be issue with your smtp configuration or any other configuration. You have to share keycloak logs to debug this issue

Answer (score 1):

Login to the Gmail account in a browser
Visit https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
Change the setting to On